# Generics and inheritance issue in Java

Tags: java, generics

Please, consider my code:

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class AWrapper<T extends A> {

}

class BWrapper<T extends B> extends AWrapper<T> {

}
```

So, I have `C extends B` etc, and `CWrapper<T extends C> extends BWrapper<T>` etc.
Now, I use these classes this way:

```
class Test {

    private Class<? extends AWrapper<? extends A>> klass;//LINE X

    public Test() {
         this.klass = BWrapper.class;//LINE Z
    }
}
```

At `LINE X` I need to set different classes - AWrapper, BWrapper, CWrapper etc. However, at `LINE Z` I get an error. Could anyone help to fix it?

Comment: Because not all of your classes share a common super class, I think `Class<?>` is the best you can do for the type of `klass`.

Comment: @markspace Yes, I can do this way, but this case I loose the constraint and I want to keep it.

Comment: But I'm saying there's no way to keep the constraint.  Generics are not covariant.  `Class<AWrapper>` is not a sub type of `Class<BWrapper>`  You can't assign one to the other.  Generic aren't meant for this sort of problem.

Comment: Your BWrapper class already extends  AWrapper in 

"class BWrapper<T extends B> extends AWrapper<T>"

Comment: Again if you say  this.klass = BWrapper.class;//LINE Z, then it means 

BWrapper.class extends AWrapper, AWrapper (twice)

because of line private Class<? extends AWrapper<? extends A>> klass;//LINE X

Comment: Thats why u get the error, hope it makes sense

Comment: @markspace actually, the best you can get is a `private Class<? extends AWrapper> klass`, I guess. it's like doing `new ArrayList<Integer>` and calling `getClass` on that instance, you will get a `ArrayList.class` - the generics are gone

Comment: @Eugene I don't think so.  `AWrapper` is generic, and you shouldn't use the raw type there.  Add in a generic wildcard for it and see what happens, I don't think it'll be good.

Comment: More generally, you don't get "an error", you get _a specific error_, and you should include the error message.

Comment: @markspace yeah, a raw type is of no good, but, how will you otherwise restrict to a "class of a subtype (or self) of AWrapper"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imho, what you are looking for is :

```
private Class<? extends AWrapper> klass;
```

even if `AWrapper` is raw. At least this way you could say that your parameter takes "a class that is subtype (or self) of `AWrapper`". But that should be the thing you care about anyway. Generics are not preserved at runtime, so no matter what `Class` you have there, it is going to be without its inferred parameters.